# Swift UIButton with questionmark

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is it possible to add this button type of button to my project:
[image]

I remember I've heard about `bezel`, but not sure if that is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `UIButton`, and set it's `cornerRadius`:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
button.clipsToBounds = true
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
```